# Can I include the animation from a SVG file into the Android splash screen?

Tags: android, animation, svg, splash-screen

The other day i was looking around with loading screens for website, and i bumped into a video - [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lmFMsrLgwM) . So i started wondering weather we could svg files in Android projects, as like , for splash screens... So can anyone tell it is possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG support on android is less. However in API level 21 they have added something called [AnimatedVectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html). It is a bit complex to use. It involves converting your SVG file to a string. Check out this video on YouTube. This shows how to use the AnimatedVectorDrawable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoFkPh3qdMU&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=35

There was a library called [MrVector](https://github.com/telly/MrVector). But it deprecated now.

Comment: Yup that is close enough... Thanks Mr.Neeraj Lal :)